# Count occurrences based on another column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a table:

```
origin    fans
USA        67
UK         56
GERMANY    56
USA        55
UK         76
GERMANY    43
USA        51
GERMANY    48
```

This data frame is called `music_fans`. How do I add a column based on the total fans per country where the third column looks like this:

```
origin    fans  total_fans
USA        67   173
UK         56    183
GERMANY    56    147
USA        55    173
UK         76    183
GERMANY    43    147
USA        51    173
UK         51    183
GERMANY    48    147
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the sum for the group with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

music_fans %>%
  group_by(origin) %>%
  mutate(total_fans = sum(fans, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Output**

```
  origin   fans total_fans
  <chr>   <int>      <int>
1 USA        67        173
2 UK         56        183
3 GERMANY    56        147
4 USA        55        173
5 UK         76        183
6 GERMANY    43        147
7 USA        51        173
8 UK         51        183
9 GERMANY    48        147
```

Or with base R:

```
music_fans$total_fans <- ave(music_fans$fans, music_fans$origin, FUN = sum, na.rm = T)
```

**Data**

```
music_fans <- structure(list(origin = c("USA", "UK", "GERMANY", "USA", "UK", 
"GERMANY", "USA", "UK", "GERMANY"), fans = c(67L, 56L, 56L, 55L, 76L, 
43L, 51L, 51L, 48L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the data table approach:

```
setDT(df)[, .(total_fans = sum(fans)), by = 'origin'] %>% 
 left_join(df, by = 'origin')
```

Comment: 1. post is a duplicate. 2. OP is asking for a dplyr solution. 3. data.table solution would be `setDT(music_fans)[, total_fans := sum(fans), by = origin]` no need for join.